# Jump to the include file in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I have a following include in my C source file (of a kernel module)

```
#include <linux/regmap.h>
```

Is there any way to quickly open this file in Atom?

Comment: ctrl+click does not perform anything?

Comment: Not at all. But this doesn't jump to the definition of a struct either, when ctrl+clicking on a struct name

Comment: Open keybindings settings, find the "open link" and key bind it

Comment: I don't have an open link when I search through my keybindings